# How to load JSON data with jQuery, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to create a dynamic dropdown menu that one select is based on the value of another select. I tried so many times and failed. I have the code as follows. Anyone can help me to find out what the problem is.

//template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(function(){ 
  getSelectVal(); 
  $("#grouptypes").change(function(){ 
      getSelectVal(); 

  }); 
});

function getSelectVal(){ 
    $.getJSON('<?php echo url_for('group_utilization/GroupModification') ?>', {'grouptypes':$("#grouptypes").val()},function(data){ 
        var groups = $("#groups"); 
        $("option",groups).remove(); 
        $.each(json,function(index,array){ 
            var option = "<option value='"+array['id']+"'>"+array['title']+"</option>"; 
            select.append(option); 
        }); 
    }); 
} 

</script>

GroupType: <select id="grouptypes">

  <?php foreach($grouptypes as $type) : ?>

  <?php echo "<option value='" . $type->name . "'>" .$type->name. "</option>"; ?>

  <?php endforeach ?>

</select><br />
<br />Result:<span id="list-of-groups"></span>

<br />
Group: <select name="group" id="groups">

</select><br />
```

Another file for returning database returned value:

```
if(isset($_GET["grouptypes"])){
 $grouptypes = $_GET["grouptypes"];

 $query = "SELECT g.name FROM groups g INNER JOIN group_types gt ON(gt.id = g.group_type_id AND gt.name = ?)";

 $groups = $db->getResultsForQuery($query, $grouptypes);
 echo json_encode($groups);
 }
```

Comment: When you say you failed, what do you mean?  Do you have any error messages you could post?

Comment: Are there any script errors? You seem to be referring to an uninitialized variable json `$.each(json,function(index,array){`

Comment: As well as the `json` variable, the `select` variable is not being initialized in the code you have posted.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: grouptypes in /Users/alexhu/Work/menagerie/trunk/apps/utilities/modules/group_utilization/actions/actions.class.php on line 47

Answer (score 1):

Does your PHP Script sends the appropriate headers for JSON ?

try to put this juste before "echo json_encode($groups);".
Eventually put an exit call to avoid extra output.

> $groups = $db->getResultsForQuery($query, $grouptypes);
>   **header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');**
>   echo json_encode($groups);
>   **exit();**

Answer (score 0):

Should the top block of code actually be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  getSelectVal(); 
  $("#grouptypes").change(function(){ 
      getSelectVal(); 

  }); 
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` is the exact same thing as `$(function () {});`. Here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the  tag with jQuery var before appending:

```
function getSelectVal(){ 
  var select = $("#grouptypes");

  $.getJSON('<?php echo url_for('group_utilization/GroupModification') ?>', {'grouptypes':$("#grouptypes").val()},function(data){ 
    var groups = $("#groups"); 
    $("option",groups).remove(); 
    $.each(data,function(index,array){ 
        var option = "<option value='"+array['id']+"'>"+array['title']+"</option>"; 
        select.append(option); 
    }); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Ron. thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work either. It is not able to get the value passed by Json and isset($_GET["grouptypes"]) is  false. I am confused

Comment: Don't you want to use the passed "data" argument instead of "json" in $.each(json... - I changed to answer above to reflect this change. Hopefully this will resolve the "isset" operation.

Answer (score 0):

You might have problem with the way **url_for()** function as it might not be able output your link properly for getJSON to use. For example if I fiddle with something close to your code (BTW, are you using Symphony?)

```
 $.post("<? echo 'server.php';?>", function(data) {
                    aler(data);

                    });

            });
```

I get this link in my JS code

```
http://dev.wonderland/%3C?%20echo%20'server.php'?%3E
```

which is obviously not the link I am trying to reach to. Also, make sure to add a semicolon at the end of your PHP code up there and try it again.